# How to Calculate Arbitrage Optimal amount in, in Uniswap v3 pools?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, uniswap, decentralized-exchange, flash-loans

Let us assume that there is an arbitrage opportunity in uniswap v3 pools.Now I want to take a flash loan to make a swap in uniswap v3 pools.My doubt is how can I calculate the optimal amount in for the arbitrage opportunity in pools.So that I can take the needed amount as flash loan.I know how it was calculated for uniswap v3 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9EKksG-fF1k&t=224s.

Comment: Because Uniswap v3 pools liquidity is not uniformly distributed, you cannot calculate the optimal arbitrage amount by not having pulling out all liquidity tick data first.

Comment: hello @MikkoOhtamaa .Can you explain more clearly or the steps that I have to follow to calculate the amount in

Comment: Sorry, just here to comment that you might have a false expectation how it works.